# calculate end date from duration

Tags: php, jquery-ui, date

I have a `duration` drop down menu with options 'yearly/quarterly/monthly' and `start date` textbox with datepicker. There is another textbox end_date.

Based on the duration I need the end date when duration and start date is selected.

**E.g.:** Start date is `23-09-2015` and duration chosen is `3 months` so, I need to display `23-12-2015`.But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Look into `strtotime();` It should do what you are looking for.

Comment: so, *anything* you tried yourself?

Comment: Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. In particular, look at the [`DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method.

Comment: I used strtotime. I stored start time in $dt and then $endt=strtotime("+1 month" ,$dt);

Comment: But I am getting no idea how to synchronize with a duration option

Comment: What do you mean synchronize with a duration option? Create a logic that determines whether it's months / weeks / days and then a simple `strtotime("+" . $calculatedDura, $dt);` should do it.

Comment: @PuJADuTtA please look at my answer for adding an interval to a date. It's simple and a build in "feature" of php 5.3+ ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This is an example. I hope this will help.

```
<?php
  $date = date("Y-m-d");

  $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +3 month");
  echo date("Y-m-d",$date);
?>
```

If you need to add months and date do like this

```
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +3 month 2 day");
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP (5.3+) has a neat class to help adding a duration to a date its called DateInterval. (it has many other nice interval features as well)

```
$date = new DateTime('2015-10-02');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P3M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2016-01-02
```

In the example above i add 3 months to my date. You can do other more complex things like P4Y1M2D, which is 2 days, 1 month and 4 years....

See php doc for more information: [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

For a tutorial go here: [Add a duration or interval to a date](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2014/01/add-a-duration-or-interval-to-a-date/)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $date = date_create('2015-09-30');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('3 Months'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#start_date").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker(
            { 
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function(selectedDate)
                {
                    var d = new Date( selectedDate );

                    if($('.date_range').val() == 'Yearly')
                    {
                        d.setFullYear( d.getFullYear( ) + 1 );                  
                    }

                    if($('.date_range').val() == 'Quarterly')
                    {
                        d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) + 3 );                
                    }

                    if($('.date_range').val() == 'Monthly')
                    {
                        d.setMonth( d.getMonth( ) + 1 );                
                    }

                    year = d.getFullYear();             
                    month = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                    date = ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2);

                    end_date = year +'-'+month+'-'+date;

                    $('#end_date').val(end_date);
                }
            });

    });
    </script>
    <select name="date_range" class="date_range">
      <option value="None">Please select a date range</option>
      <option value="Yearly">Yearly</option>
      <option value="Quarterly">Quarterly</option>
      <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
    </select>
    <p>Start Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" id="start_date" />
    <p>End Date</p>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" id="end_date" />
```